# Exclude certain column from Entity Framework select statment

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an image column in the product table in a SQL Server database. The image column is used to save the images as bytes.

I know it is better to make a separate table for images, but I did not do that,
so is there any way to exclude the image column when I am trying to list the products only without the images?

Comment: `yourDbSet.Select(x => new YourType { DesiredProperty =  x.DesiredProperty, ... })`

Comment: It would be great if there was an rxJS-like map operator, which you could use to null out a property before the query executes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a DTO with all the properties you need except the image property:

```
public class YourDTO
{
    public string YourProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string YourProperty2 { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

You can then do:

```
var productDto = context.Products
                        .Where(x => x.Id == productId)
                        .Select(x => new YourDTO {
                            YourProperty1 = x.DbProperty1,
                            YourProperty2 = x.DbProperty2        
                            // etc, don't include the image column
                        });
```

Update:

If you don't want to map the results to `YourDTO`, you can project into an anonymous type:

```
var product = context.Products
                     .Where(x => x.Id == productId)
                     .Select(x => new {
                         x.DbProperty1,
                         x.DbProperty2        
                         // etc, don't include the image column
                     });
```

...and if you want to provide a custom name for each of the properties of the anonymous type:

```
var product = context.Products
                     .Where(x => x.Id == productId)
                     .Select(x => new {
                         YourProperty1 = x.DbProperty1,
                         YourProperty2 = x.DbProperty2        
                         // etc, don't include the image column
                     });
```

All of the above approaches would be functionally equivalent to the following SQL:

```
SELECT p.DbProperty1, p.DbProperty2 
FROM products p
WHERE p.Id = WhateverId;
```

Comment: Wouldn't custom mapping on DTO be not sufficient enough?

Comment: Why would it be "not sufficient enough"? The query would be translated on the SQL side as `SELECT dbProperty1, dbProperty2 FROM Product`. You can also project to an anonymous type instead - see my update.

Comment: That's what I meant. "It will be translated to the SQL" so you could only make a DTO and map it accordingly. From what I know EF has automated this process enough to just create that DTO and map it.

Comment: Can this work with a grandparent `.Include()`? If you have a navigational property to a grandparent entity, the fields get lost from the query...

Comment: The anonymous type solution (last code example) was exactly what I was looking for. I have some columns with lots of data in them which I want to exclude from the select. This is a small and elegant solution for this.

Answer (score -4):

```
product.Entity<Product>().Exclude(e => e.image);
```

or

```
product.Entity<Product>().Ignore(e => e.image);
```

Comment: i am using code first approach and at the same time , i cant find the except and ignore , here down my statement                     ctx.Products.Where(p => p.isActive == true).OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList().Select(p => ProductInformation.Create(p));    where ProductInformation is a typescript class

Comment: @Laila You've called `ToList()` which executes the whole query and dumps it into the `List<>` object.

Comment: where do i find either Exclude or Ignore is this an ef core thing?

Comment: @Seabizkit you need to add System.Data.Entity reference

Comment: You haven't provided any context at all, that's why I gave you a -1. I guess your suggestion is based on the `OnModelCreating` method of the `DbContext` class? And so it isnt a way to ignore on select, but ignore for the complete `DbContext`.

Comment: These `Exclude` and `Ignore` methods look ideal, but they appear not to exist.